# ng-dropzone module does not work in my AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, dropzone

I am using [ng-dropzone](https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone) in my AngularJS and following the steps according to its documentation but I get the following error:

> *TypeError: o is not a constructor
>       at Object.link (http://localhost/myAngularJSApp/lib/bower/ng-dropzone/dist/ng-dropzone.min.js:1:440)*

The sequence of loading dependencies are:

1. angular.js
2. dropzone.js
3. ng-dropzone.min.js

I found out that all the files are loaded properly but I don't know where is the problem!?

Comment: can you provide a plunkar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, I found the issue and I decided to share with others who may have the same issue.

In this case the problem is with version of ng-dropzone. Previously, I used v2.0.2 (the latest version) and I downgraded it to v2.0.1. Moreover, my angularjs version is 1.5.11.